# keep contents of textview till a button is pressed

Tags: ios, textview

I have been looking for a code to keep the contents of the textview ,till i click on a back button or a done button on the same page. But when i gave the code:

```
(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    myTextView.text = nil;
}
```

Every time(even before completing the text) , if i press the return button of keyboard and click on text view again to type the rest, the already existed text clears away.

I have kept the above code for clearing the default text "*Enter your text*", when the textview is shown for the first time.

I have been working by setting booleans, but could't get the result! Please if someone could clear me out of this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

if ([myTextView isEqualToString:@"Enter your text"]) {
    myTextView.text = nil;
    }

}
```

This code will check that is your text is equal to `Enter your text` and if it is than it will clear otherwise not.